# Нижний TitleBar в Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Добрый день!

Суть дела: есть кнопочка в самом низу разметки, и при отображении клавиатуры ее, соответственно, не видно. Есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы при открытии клавиатуры кнопочка эта выезжала по разметке вверх и отображалась над открывшейся клавиатурой?

Спасибо!

Comment: @Igor Fedorov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В манифесте для активити укажите   `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`